# Java2d: Set gradient for a lines

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d

I am having multiple points in a plane and some hundreds of lines pass through those points. Some points can have more lines passing through them than other points. I want to show some kind of more gradient or brightness associated with lines crowded together. Is this possible to do in java2d.

Please refer to this : http://ft.ornl.gov/doku/_media/ft/projects/paraxis.jpg

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That picture looks like just a bunch of lines drawn with a low alpha value - in other words, using a nearly transparent color. When you have a lot of lines close together, they'll overlap and the color will get brighter. So, assuming the picture shows the kind of effect you're looking for, just use one of the `Color` constructors with four arguments and specify a low alpha value for the last one (maybe 0.1 as a float, or 20-30 as an int), then go crazy drawing your lines ;-)

If that doesn't do what you want, maybe I misunderstood your question...